# How to not lose line breaks when sending a text via post

Tags: javascript, php, html, http

Hey I have the following problem: I want to send some text from a textarea per POST to a php script which writes it in a file and displays it on the website. But when I do this the line breaks disappear and the displayed text looks kind of ugly.

JS:

```
let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        document.querySelector(".displayMessage").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};

xhttp.open("POST", "submitMessage.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

let params = "message=" + document.querySelector("#nachricht").value;
xhttp.send(params);
```

php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message'] != "") {
   $write = fopen('counter/message.txt', 'w');
   fwrite($write, $_POST['message']);
}

echo $visitors = file_get_contents('counter/message.txt');
```

Comment: HTML doesn't display normal line breaks. You need to convert the line breaks to HTML-line breaks: `<br />`. You can use [nblr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for that like this: `echo nblr($theText);`

Comment: perhaps your element need the css: `white-space: pre`? or you could use the `<pre>` element instead?

Comment: Is it contains line breaks on client side ? try console.log the display message and tell us

Comment: @MagnusEriksson exactly what I needed, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply the below css on the div or the element in which you show the text.

```
div {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function display() {
 let elem = document.getElementById('content');
 document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = elem.innerHTML;
}
```

```css
div {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="content">This is some text   with some extra spacing    and a
    few newlines along with some trailing spaces        
         and five leading spaces thrown in
    for                                              good
    measure   </textarea>
  
  <div id="display"></div>
  
  <button onclick="display()">Display</button>
```